# socket.io binary support documentation

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Can anyone point me to any sort of documentation for how to implement binary on socket.io? Its listed that they have added the support a few months ago, but i cant find any documentation for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket.IO doesn't support binary data as not all transports support this. What you should do instead is taking a look at http://binaryjs.com/

If you do not want to such a solution you will have to pack all your binary data in to a string and decode it again on the client side.. But this is basically the same that binaryjs is also doing. It using a customized messagepack (encoder) to send the data see https://github.com/binaryjs/js-binarypack

Comment: As an update to this comment, it appears Socket.IO is adding binary support in their upcoming release, see https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/commit/745ee03102e7e5f780346054d0859ff1d8da839b

Comment: Update: Socket.IO now supports binary! :)

Answer (score 2):

As of now, [since 2014 (v1.0) Socket.IO supports binary files](http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#binary). I also wrote a [blog post](http://blog.castillobg.co/programming/tutorial/golang/2015/11/10/socket-io-file-transfer.html) about how to use it (since I found the docs to be somewhat lacking)

Answer (score 1):

There's one more module which helps greatly for sending binary dta with socket.io

Try deliveryjs

> https://github.com/liamks/Delivery.js

which provides the means of binary data communication between clients and server via socket.io. (but uses base64 conversion method)

Answer (score 1):

Updating for people who get here, take a look at [socket.io-stream](https://www.npmjs.org/package/socket.io-stream)